# Tableau - blend, join, or modify raw?

Tags: pandas, tableau-api

I have several large files which have metric information. I am linking these files to a roster database so I know who an employee reported to on a certain date (this allows me to track performance per manager or per site, etc).

The way I am doing this is creating a RosterID field which is EmployeeID+Date (Example: x112x20141022). So if I filter on one sheet on my dashboard, it will filter for all sheets.

Question: Do I use a blend between the files (there are about 8 different data sources right now), a left join, or do I just use python/pandas to literally add the information to the raw data source? I want the twbx file to be as fast as possible for the end users.

(What I mean by adding the information to the raw data is literally adding columns like Manager, Director, Location, Hire Date, Training Class. This would add to the file sizes marginally, but would it speed up Tableau?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data blend (creating a relationship between different datasources in Tableau) is the worst performing solution. While it is easy to use, it's highly inefficient, because it will virtually perform the join every single time a calculation is made.

Performing a left join on Tableau when connecting to data (I'm assuming you're using csv files) is a very good solution, as is making a single table with the information in Pandas. For the final user, there shouldn't bet any difference in performance (especially if you extract the data to tde in Tableau). Here you need to measure if it's easier for you to maintain a process in python/pandas or in Tableau extracting tool. I believe it's simpler to have Tableau doing the join. But it's your call

Comment: So perhaps I will add a file called RosterDatabase which has the daily ID+Date figures and the corresponding information (manager, location, etc). Then I will left join that with my larger raw files which have the ID+Date unique ID. Does that seem like a fair solution?

Comment: Yes, anything that will give you a single table in Tableau (after extract) is very fair.

Comment: Server side joins are in fact more efficient than client side data blends, but data blends can be very useful and reasonably efficient when used well. Blending is one of the few options available for combining data drawn dynamically from different sources, say comparing a spreadsheet to related data in a database. Blending can cause some complex behavior behind the scenes and you have to pay careful attention to the blending fields (analogous to join keys). It's an advanced feature. Not for every situation, but very useful when needed.

Comment: Indeed, I like using data blending to use a correspondence table, something like I have the product Id in my master table, and a secondary table with the product description for each Id. Unless you have millions of products (I have tens of thousands), it's pretty fast (and easy to use) =D